# What (if ever) is the context at which I should use the term "various and sundries?

Tags: expressions

My neighbor uses the term/phrase "various and sundries" all the time, but first off, it seems like he just means the word "various" alone, but adds "and sundries" to it for some reason. And then once in a while I'll hear someone else say it. But what context is it supposed to properly be used in, if I should even try to use it at all?

Answer (score 0):

Do note that the phrase is termed as **'Various and sundry'**.

According to [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/various-and-sundry), **various and sundry** means:

> of different kinds, miscellaneous, as in Various and sundry items did not sell, so they'll probably hold another auction. This expression is a redundancy, the two adjectives meaning just about the same thing.

Also, [Pleonasm](http://members.authorsguild.net/chelster/pleonasm__a_word_every_writer_and_copyeditor_should_know_117771.htm), in which I quote,

> Fowler notes that many pleonastic set phrases were created (not originally created) to achieve emphasis, but because of overuse they now invariably wind up “boring rather than striking the hearer.” Many of these—such as any and all; fit and proper; aid and abet; save and except; sole and exclusive; null and void; terms and conditions; cease and desist; and ***various and sundry***—have been adopted from legal jargon. Other common pleonastic twins that usage authorities find objectionable include if and when; unless and until; compare and contrast (from educationese); first and foremost; and the much-despised each and every. The prudent copyeditor will completely eradicate such clichéd pairs.

Answer (score 0):

"Various and sundry" (singular) is an English language cliche meaning, just as you correctly pointed out, "various." As a cliche, I recommend that you **not** try to incorporate it into your speech or writing; it is just a bad habit on the part of your neighbor. For more information, check out this: [When is it appropriate to use the idiom "various and sundry"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151560/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-the-idiom-various-and-sundry) (With thanks to **Brian Donovan**.)